# How to execute javascript after filling in a form using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Just getting started with selenium, this is the HTML of the page:

```
<div id="signInForm">
    <form action="/cgi-bin/VmLoginCgi" method="POST" name="signIn1" id="signIn">
        <h2 id="loginTitle">Sign in to view and change your settings</h2>
        <div class="field formField noHint username clearfix">
            <label for="username"></label>
        </div>
        <div style="position:relative;" class="field formField noHint password clearfix"><label for="password">Settings Password</label><input type="password" autocomplete="off" value="" maxlength="15" class="name required onefiftyPX inactive" name="jgwhnZLOXn" id="password" onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event)"></div>

        <div>
            <a href="javascript:SignIn()" class="newCta ctaLarge ctaPrimaryLarge floatLeft">Sign In</a>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p>
        <span style="font-weight:bold;">Don't know your password?</span><br>You'll find your default password on the bottom of your Super Hub.
    </p>
</div>
```

I'm filling in the text box by doing:

```
ele = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
ele.send_keys("supersecretpassword")
```

But can't submit the actual form by executing the javascript. I've tried:

```
 browser.execute_script("SignIn()")
```

But get a big long error, any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit the form with `submit()`:

```
ele.submit()
```

It would find the element's parent form and submit it.

Or, if that's not gonna work in your case, find the `Sign In` button and click it:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Sign In").click()
```

Comment: Ah yes, second one worked for me. Really quite clever this selenium! Thanks alex.